# What is wrong with my code for assigning onfocus event to the element?

Tags: javascript, onfocus

I have a following code which I tried to assign onfocus event to the element, so that whenever the element gets focused, call alert. 
However, alert only appears when the page loaded, and never after that.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload = "loadings();">
<div>   
    <form>  
        <input type="text" id="foo"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadings(){
    document.getElementById("foo").onfocus = alert("foo"); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I can't do `<input type="text" id="foo" onfocus="alert('foo')"/>` for the thing I am trying to achieve.

Also this should work in Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onfocus = alert("foo");
```

assigns the *result* of calling alert() to the onfocus property.
What you meant is:

```
document.getElementById("foo").onfocus = function(){ alert("foo"); };
```

This is using the DOM Level 0 event model where you can only have one handler per event. If you want something more flexible while still cross-platform then you may try some library to abstract the event model for you like jQuery does:

```
$('#foo').focus(function(){ alert("foo"); });
```

That way you don't have to worry about attachEvent in IE vs. addEventListener in everything else, but if you only need the simple case like in your example then the Level 0 model is perfectly fine and works across all browsers.

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the second excerpt.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much! That's what I wanted!!

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing semicolon - fixed. Though the code would still work thanks to the infamous semicolon insertion in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

rsp's answer is correct, and is in my opinion a better style. To better understand the solution compare this syntax with rsp's. Both achieve the same result.

```
function MyEventHandler ()
{
    alert("foo");
}

document.getElementById("foo").onfocus = MyEventHandler;
```

The key thing to remember with the syntax is you include the function name, but not the parentheses (). You want to refer to the function itself, not invoke it.  The event will invoke the function when it is raised.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the addeventlistener like below.

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("focus", function(){alert("foo")}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic function to add an event handler

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ){
    if(!obj){
        return;
    }
    if (obj.addEventListener){
        obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
    }
    else{
        if (obj.attachEvent){
            obj["e"+type+fn] = fn;
            obj[type+fn] = function() { obj["e"+type+fn]( window.event ); }
            obj.attachEvent( "on"+type, obj[type+fn] );
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('foo'),'focus',myEventhandler);
```